# Help using Google's SMTP server in J

Tags: smtp, ssl, j

As part of a Computer Science class, we are learning some socket programming in J and have gotten our programs to send e-mails through the school's SMTP server and receive from our own ISP, simply because those are the simplest examples. However, the school does not allow access from outside their own physical computers, so I cannot send mail from my home computer, making it impossible to work on certain things.

I would like some help with the basics of how to negotiate Google's TLS conversation in order to send e-mail via my code. I have attempted to read the RFC's and am confused as to whether I send a sort of pseudocode to them with some extra bytes, or if there's actually some English involved. It would be great if you could answer with respect to J, but if not, I will be grateful for any help at all.

Comment: Would be to switch your SMTP server to be your local ISP SMTP server?

Comment: I agree with @PaulWhelan, it would seem like a viable approach to consider standard SMTP first.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I already tried that and while it successfully negotiates the SMTP conversation, it only sends once every 20 or so times. It looks like I'm such a low priority to the ISP's server, it doesn't even send my e-mails via this method. That's why I wanted to try Google: for reliability for each send.

Comment: Get a real\virtual machine with SMTP server running. Will save you lots on effort. There are a lot preconfigured virtual appliances for VirtualBox\VMware player.